# How can I get a boolean value for whether there are modified files in a SVN repository?

Tags: bash, svn

I would like to obtain a boolean value on whether a certain SVN reposity has been modified in the meanwhile so that I can be notified on changes. Ideally I don't want to execute `svn update` for that.

Comment: Are you just checking the local (working repository) or checking a working repository against the remote repository?  The two scenarios are quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : It looks like you just need to use `svn status -u` on your local copy root and check for the 9th column. If it's empty, your repo is up to date.
I can't try it out but that's what [this doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) states, please tell me if I'm wrong

---

Use `svn info` against your local copy and the corresponding repository url, compare revision lines.